# What the difference between using component.PropTypes and interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

while creating a react component i can define type in these two methods, but i want to know the difference between these two,

### Method 1

```
const MyComponent:React.FC<IProps> = () => (<></>)

interface IProps {
   Title: string
}
```

### Method 2

```
const MyComponent:React.FC = () => (<></>)

MyComponent.propTypes = {
Title: string
}
```

what is the difference between these two type defining.

### while iam trying i got a error,

In method one i tried to add

```
const MyComponent:React.FC<IProps> = () => (<></>)

interface IProps {
   Title: React.FC
}
```

but, while adding the same thing to the proptype it got error

```
const MyComponent:React.FC = () => (<></>)

MyComponent.propTypes = {
Title: React.FC
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`propTypes` has nothing to do with TypeScript; [it's a run-time/lint-time check that  React and certain React tools know of](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

The allowed prop types are separate from the TypeScript type system, which is why using `React.FC` in `propTypes` is an error.

(`MyComponent.propTypes = {Title: string}` is also incorrect, but doesn't cause an error – just that the actual propTypes is `{Title: undefined}`, which doesn't help.)

Additionally, you don't want to use `React.FC` unless your component accepts the `children` prop (and even so, you could just use `React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>`).

IOW,

```
interface Props {
   title: string;
}
function MyComponent({title}: Props) {
  return <h1>{title}</h1>;
}
```

is enough and gives you compile-time type checking for `MyComponent`.